# How to change the order of jquery events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 events here one is `click` and one is `focus` on the input, I need the click to run before focus so I added a timeout to it but I feel like this isn't an elegant solution.

```
  $(document).click(function(e) {
        var target = e.target;
        var lastElement = '#' + lastList;
        console.log('here first');
        if (!$(target).is(lastElement) && !$(target).parent().parent().is(lastElement) && !$(target).parent().parent().parent(lastElement).is(lastElement)) {
            $('.add-card .fa-plus').show();
            $(lastElement).children().children().children('textarea').addClass('pl-8 bg-gray-200');
            $(lastElement).children().children().children('textarea').removeClass('h-20 px-4 w-60 resize bg-white');
            $('.js-add-card-button').addClass('hidden')
        }
    });
    
    $(document).on('focus', '.js-create-card', function(e) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('here');
            $(this).siblings('.add-card .fa-plus').hide();
            $(this).removeClass('pl-8 bg-gray-200');
            $(this).addClass('h-20 px-4 w-60 resize bg-white');
            $(this).siblings('.js-add-card-button').removeClass('hidden');
            lastList = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
        }, 100);
    });
```

So I have a few questions about the solution I used:

1. Is there a async-await solution to this problem?
2. The 100ms delay works for me but will it work on all PCs? Can a slower PC ruin this structure?

Comment: Well, if what happens on focus should happen after click, why not just move the code from the focus event to the end of the click event?

Comment: @crimson589 you mean nest the focus inside click?

Comment: I mean just remove the focus event and put whatever code you have there to the click event.

Comment: @TurqayUmudzade Are you able to provide a minimal working example of this code please ?

Comment: @crimson589 that would not work I am afraid, I need the focus event.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping too much code for me to cut, but basically a Trello board, where on input focus it expands the div and adds a button under it, and when clicked somewhere else it goes back to normal, the problem is having multiple elements.

Comment: @TurqayUmudzade why not a focusout event then? instead of click.

Comment: @crimson589 because on focus out the button is unclickable since it will make it hidden as soon as I press on it since focus out (blur) runs first,